# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string - in github version and tag

Tags: scala, github, sbt, gitversion, version-sort

I made a release in version v1.0.0-a1 on github and I launched the build on jenkins, until there all worked very well then I create a new tag v1.0.0-a2 on github and I relaunch a build. Since I have this error at the compilation: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0-a2"`

I then delete the tag v1.0.0-a2 and I create a new v1.0.1-a1 but I still have the same error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0-a2"`even after deleting the tag and the build on Jenkins

How can I fix this problem,
Thanks for everything

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "relaunch a build"? Are you using a plugin? Is that your code that throws this exception? Post the fill stacktrace maybe. Without more information, we cannot help.